# Invalid parameter: redirect_uri Angular 14 keycloak spring boot

Tags: keycloak, angular14, spring-boot-3

I have enabled URL in the Keycloak console admin. Logging in works fine, but I encounter an issue when trying to log out. I receive the following error:

GET http://localhost:8080/realms/securityKeyCloak/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200 400 (Bad Request)

```
function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: 'http://localhost:8080',
        realm: 'securityKeyCloak',
        clientId: 'keycloak_breif_angular'
      },
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
          window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html'
      }
    });
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OSCZ.jpg)

Could you please assist me in resolving this problem?